# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout (Help needed)

Tags: java, android, api, rest, android-studio

i'm building an application that connects to my Drupal API. Somehow i'm not getting any data display within my application. I don't see any errors in the code and the debugging online gives the follow error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.eindopdrachtcmsapi;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener {

    public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String EXTRA_BODY = "body";
    public static final String EXTRA_LINK = "link";


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON();


    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        String url = "http://vistudio.be/api/portfolio";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject portfolio = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                String title = portfolio.getString("title");
                                String body = portfolio.getString("body");
                                String link = portfolio.getString("field_website_url");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(title, body, link));

                            }

                            mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
                            mExampleAdapter.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this, new ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(int position) {
                                    ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

                                    String title = clickedItem.getTitle();
                                    String Link = clickedItem.getLink();

                                    Intent mSharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    mSharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                    mSharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Vistudio");
                                    mSharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title + " - "+ Link);
                                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mSharingIntent, "Share"));
                                }
                            });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, clickedItem.getTitle());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_BODY, clickedItem.getBody());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_LINK, clickedItem.getLink());
        mExampleAdapter.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this, new ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

                String title = clickedItem.getTitle();
                String Link = clickedItem.getLink();

                Intent mSharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mSharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                mSharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Vistudio");
                mSharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title + " - "+ Link);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mSharingIntent, "Share"));
            }
        });
        startActivity(detailIntent);



    }

}
```

My Adapter code:

```
package com.example.eindopdrachtcmsapi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.portfolioViewHolder>{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private onItemClickListener mListener;
    private onItemClickListener mListenerShare;

    public interface onItemClickListener{

        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener listener, onItemClickListener listenerShare){
        mListener = listener;
        mListenerShare = listenerShare;
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> ExampleList) {
        mContext = context;
        mExampleList = ExampleList;
    }


    @Override
    public portfolioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.exampleitem, parent, false);
        return new portfolioViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(portfolioViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        String title = currentItem.getTitle();
        String body = currentItem.getBody();
        String link = currentItem.getLink();

        holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(title);
        holder.mTextViewBody.setText(body);
        holder.mTextViewLink.setText(link);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class portfolioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mTextViewTitle;
        public TextView mTextViewBody;
        public TextView mTextViewLink;
        public Button mButton;

        public portfolioViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            mTextViewBody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_body);
            mTextViewLink = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_link);
            mButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListenerShare != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListenerShare.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first remove inside oncreate()

```
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```

after this code

```
 mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```

add this:-

```
mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I did this but i still get an empty emmulator app. It's just the name of my app and a white screen without any data from my API.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout